# How to display nested list and maintain MVC pattern?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Attempting to display nested list using MVC 6 and EF code first design.  I'm using this [Tutorial](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc.html) to get me started with MVC and am trying to take it to another level.

Classes:

```
public class Location
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SubLocation> Sublocations { get; set; }
    }
}

public class SubLocation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SubLocationName { get; set; }
}
```

Running `dnx ef database update` sets up my EF database correctly and assigns a foreign key to `LocationID` under `SubLocation`.

[image]

---

Now I want to display Sub Locations under each Location like the following image.  The user can add new locations or sub locations tied to a location.

[image]

---

Displaying the list of locations is simple: `return View(_context.Location.ToList());`

To display the nested list of sub-locations, should I do the work in the controller or view?

I was hoping I could just use the view like the following but `item.Sublocations` is `null` for a reason that I'm not sure of since there is data in the database.:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationName)</td>
  </tr>

  @foreach (SubLocation itm in item.Sublocations)
  {
    <tr>
        <td>@itm.SubLocationName</td>
    </tr>
  }
}
```

---

I've tried creating a query in the controller but the foreign key isn't available to compare against.

```
var test = (from m in _context.SubLocation
            where m.LocationID == curLocID   <-- m.LocationID isn't available
            select m.SubLocationName
            ).ToList();
```

Even if I could use the LocationID I'm not sure how to send the current Location (curLocID) from the View back to the controller.  I think I need a helper method but I'm starting to go in circles.

How can I maintain proper MVC and display nested list from a subclass of my main class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider adding a `LocationID` property to your `SubLocation` class which will be the foreign key to the `Location` table.

```
public class SubLocation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SubLocationName { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { set;get;}
}
```

Now, query the locations. Location has a `SubLocations` property,so your view should work fine.

```
var locations = _context.Locations.Include(s=>s.SubLocations).ToList();
return View(locations);
```

Comment: That worked great and I like how clean it is.  I kept trying to get the data through a separate method not realizing I could just pass it with the main view.  Light bulb moment.  Thanks!