# How to bind a grouped Viewbag to MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a grouped list like below,

```
var Cabin_dt_CurrentDeal = Cabin_dt_Details.Where(f => f.SailingID == currentCruiseID)
                                         .GroupBy(a => a.Name).Select(grp => grp.ToList())
                                         .ToList();
ViewBag.Cabin_dt_CurrentDeal = Cabin_dt_CurrentDeal;
```

And below is the screenshot of my viewbag

[image]

what i am trying to do is, I want to bind this grouped viewbag to my view(something like below)

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Cabin_dt_CurrentDeal)
{

    <div></div>

}
```

please guide me how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: you have to loop in item too to get the list values if you want. It all depends on what information you want from this lists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display nested list and maintain MVC pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633116/how-to-display-nested-list-and-maintain-mvc-pattern)

Comment: So far you are doing well, so i don't really see where exactly you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly see the problem here, but you are on the right track.

Please provide the structure of your `Cabin_dt_CurrentDeal` list items and the exact HTML structure you need so I can edit the answer better.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Cabin_dt_CurrentDeal)
{
    <div>
        @foreach (var subitem in item.listName)
        {
            <div>
                <h3>subitem.Name</h3>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```